# Validate array keys at Laravel Request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Request where I need to validate the keys from an array.
The keys are the productId and I am checking if the product belongs to the user.

Here is an example of products at the POST request:

```
[
    8 => [
        'quantity' => 10,
        'discount' => 10
    ],
    9 => [
        'quantity' => 10,
        'discount' => 10
    ]
]
```

And bellow is the Request rules. Is it possible to check on the keys?

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'product.*' => 'required|exists:recipes,id,user_id,' . $this->user()->id,
            'product.*.quantity' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'product.*.discount' => 'required|numeric|min:0'
        ];
    }
```

Comment: As far as i know, it is not possible with the default validation rules,
However you can easly build one using a custom validation rule:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 1):

I made a temporary solution...I kept the id validation at the request.

```
 'products.*.id' => 'required|exists:recipes,id,user_id,' . $this->user()->id,
 'products.*.quantity' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
 'products.*.discount' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
```

But at the controller the data is modified to fit the sync() method where the id is removed from the object that will be modified and setted as a key.

```
 $products = [];
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['products']); $i++) {
   $recipes[$data['products'][$i]['id']] = $data['products'][$i];
   unset($products[$data['products'][$i]['id']]['id']);
 }
 $budget->products()->sync($products);
 $budget->products = $data['products'];
```

I didn't mentioned that this is a manytomany polymorphic relationships.